# Why do I have to manually escape my quotes in order for http.request. write method to send JSON

Tags: node.js, slack

When executing the below code the only way I can seam to get the `request.write()` working is by escaping the quotations manually. I have tried to `JSON.stringify()` the argument before passing it in & that still doesn't seam to work.

Any ideas on what is going on here and how to fix it?

I have tried `JSON.stringify(message)` as well as quite a few other methods. I'm also set on doing this through vanilla `https.request`.

```
function samplePost(responseURL){
    let postOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    let request = https.request(responseURL, postOptions, (res) => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on("end",() => {
            //console.log(rawData);
        });
    });

    //can't seem to send this along properly unless I escape all quotations
    //example "{ \"text\": \"Testing this message out once again...\" }"
    let message = [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Are you sure you want to invite to :video_game:?\n*" + email + "* on *" + platform + "*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "Invite"
                    },
                    "value": "invite"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "No"
                    },
                    "value": "dont_invite"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    request.write(message);
    request.end();
}
```

The above code integrates with slack.

I expect slack to output my message when `request.write(message)` is sent.

Instead what i'm left with is a blank response. As if nothing has gone wrong but no data is sent either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple issue in regards to how I was formatting my return message to slack.

I needed to ensure my slack blocks were first added to a json object with "blocks" as the the key where my blocks go. Secondly I needed to JSON.stringify the json before i sent it. See below.

```
function samplePost(responseURL){
    let postOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    let request = https.request(responseURL, postOptions, (res) => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on("end", () => { });
    });
    let messageBlocks = [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Are you sure you want to invite to :video_game:?\n*" + email + "* on *" + platform + "*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "Invite"
                    },
                    "value": "invite"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "No"
                    },
                    "value": "dont_invite"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    //ADDED THIS
    let returnMessage = {
        "blocks": messageBlocks
    }
    request.write(JSON.stringify(messageBlocks));
    request.end();
}
```